# Triggering `visibilitychange` event in test (vitest)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vitest

In my code, I set an eventListener for `visibilitychange`, and when running the code in the browser, everything works as intended. I'm trying to replicate the behavior in unit test, and am unable to do so.

##### implementation.ts

```typescript
const visibilitychangeCreativeViewHandler = () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    logger.info('Firing visibilitychange event handler');
    fireCreativeView();
  }
};

// The function that actually fires the creative view pixel - but only once. If the document
// is visible when this is triggered below and then the visibility state changes to hidden
// and then back to visible, we don't want multiple `creativeView` pixels to be fired.
const fireCreativeView = once(() => {
  for (const companion of companions) {
    if (companion.events.creativeView) {
      for (const viewEvent of companion.events.creativeView) {
        const { uri } = viewEvent;
        logger.info(`Firing creativeView pixel`);

        const pixel = document.createElement('img');
        pixel.src = uri;
        pixel.height = 1;
        pixel.width = 1;

        pixel.addEventListener('load', () => pixel.remove());

        document.body.append(pixel);
      }
    }
  }
});

// further down...

// If the document is visible, fire off the 'creativeView' event
if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
  fireCreativeView();
}
// add an event listener to fire the creativeView event if the browser becomes visible
// during the ad break
document.addEventListener(
  'visibilitychange',
  visibilitychangeCreativeViewHandler,
);
```

##### test.ts

```typescript
it('fires the pixel after visibilitychange', () => {
  const bodyAppendSpy = vi.spyOn(document.body, 'append'); // This gets called in the listener's handler
  
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'visibilityState', {
    value: 'hidden',
    writable: true,
  });
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'hidden', {
    value: true,
    writable: true,
  });

  // some other assertions on document being initially hidden...

  Object.defineProperty(document, 'visibilityState', {
    value: 'visible',
    writable: true,
  });
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'hidden', {
    value: false,
    writable: true,
  });

  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('visibilitychange'));

  expect(bodyAppendSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this assertion fails

});
```

I've tried asserting in a `setTimeout` with 0 delay and I've also tried `fireEvent` from `@testing-library/dom` to no avail.